# P2 with equinox transforms

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, transform, equinox, p2

I have to merge p2 with equinox transforms in a rcp application.
I have in my config.ini this configuration:

> osgi.bundles=org.eclipse.equinox.ds@2:\start,org.eclipse.osgi@-1:\start,org.eclipse.core.runtime@start,org.eclipse.equinox.common@2:\start,org.eclipse.equinox.transforms.xslt@1:\start,org.eclipse.equinox.transforms.xslt.plugin@1:\start
>   osgi.framework.extensions=org.eclipse.equinox.transforms.hook

I have in my transform.csv this

> org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk,transforms.product,/actionSetUpdate.xslt

in my Activator this:

```
public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        super.start(context);
        plugin = this;
        Dictionary properties = new Hashtable();
        properties.put("equinox.transformerType", "xslt");
        registration = context.registerService(URL.class.getName(), context.getBundle().getEntry("/transform.csv"), properties);
    }

    public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        plugin = null;
        super.stop(context);
        if (registration != null)
            registration.unregister();
    }
```

but it doesn't work.

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.transforms.xslt.plugin 4 0 2012-01-23
>   13:23:07.043 !MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR !STACK 0
>   org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The activator
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.transforms.xslt.plugin.Activator for
>   bundle org.eclipse.equinox.transforms.xslt.plugin is invalid  at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:171)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:679)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:389)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1130)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.transforms.xslt.plugin.Activator     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:164)
>     ... 12 more Root exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.transforms.xslt.plugin.Activator     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:164)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:679)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:389)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1130)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-01-23 13:23:07.824 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   org.eclipse.equinox.transforms.xslt.plugin_1.0.0.qualifier [59] is not
>   active.
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-01-23 13:23:07.996 !MESSAGE One or
>   more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints
>   are not resolved: !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-01-23
>   13:23:07.996 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   reference:file:/C:/Users/CSP/Desktop/eclipse-jee-indigo-SR1-win32-x86_64/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations_2.1.0.v20110511-1821.jar
>   was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations 2 0
>   2012-01-23 13:23:07.996 !MESSAGE Missing imported package
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.configurator_0.0.0. !SUBENTRY
>   1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-01-23 13:23:07.996 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   reference:file:/C:/Users/CSP/Desktop/eclipse-jee-indigo-SR1-win32-x86_64/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui_2.1.0.v20110601.jar
>   was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui 2 0 2012-01-23
>   13:23:07.996 !MESSAGE Missing imported package
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.configurator_0.0.0. !SUBENTRY
>   1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-01-23 13:23:07.996 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   reference:file:/C:/Users/CSP/Desktop/eclipse-jee-indigo-SR1-win32-x86_64/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director_2.1.0.v20110504-1715.jar
>   was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 2 0
>   2012-01-23 13:23:07.996 !MESSAGE Missing imported package
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.configurator_0.0.0.
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-01-23 13:23:08.027 !MESSAGE The
>   following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see
>   the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists: !SUBENTRY 1
>   org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-01-23 13:23:08.027 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director_2.1.0.v20110504-1715 [23] was not
>   resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 2 0 2012-01-23
>   13:23:08.027 !MESSAGE Missing imported package
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.configurator_0.0.0. !SUBENTRY
>   1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-01-23 13:23:08.027 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations_2.1.0.v20110511-1821 [28] was not
>   resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations 2 0 2012-01-23
>   13:23:08.027 !MESSAGE Missing imported package
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.director_0.0.0. !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations 2 0 2012-01-23 13:23:08.027 !MESSAGE
>   Missing imported package
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.configurator_0.0.0. !SUBENTRY
>   2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations 2 0 2012-01-23 13:23:08.027
>   !MESSAGE Missing imported package
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.director_0.0.0. !SUBENTRY
>   2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations 2 0 2012-01-23 13:23:08.027
>   !MESSAGE Missing imported package
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.planner_[2.0.0,3.0.0). !SUBENTRY 1
>   org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-01-23 13:23:08.027 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui_2.1.0.v20110601 [30] was not resolved.
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui 2 0 2012-01-23 13:23:08.027
>   !MESSAGE Missing imported package
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.director_0.0.0. !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui 2 0 2012-01-23 13:23:08.027 !MESSAGE Missing
>   imported package
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.configurator_0.0.0. !SUBENTRY
>   2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui 2 0 2012-01-23 13:23:08.027 !MESSAGE
>   Missing imported package
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations_[2.0.0,3.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui 2 0 2012-01-23 13:23:08.027 !MESSAGE Missing
>   imported package org.eclipse.equinox.p2.planner_[2.0.0,3.0.0).
>   !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-01-23 13:23:08.027 !MESSAGE
>   Bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk_1.0.200.v20110502-1955 [31] was
>   not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk 2 0 2012-01-23
>   13:23:08.027 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui_0.0.0. !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk 2 0 2012-01-23 13:23:08.027 !MESSAGE
>   Missing optionally required bundle org.eclipse.compare_0.0.0.
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk 2 0 2012-01-23 13:23:08.027
>   !MESSAGE Missing imported package
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations_[2.0.0,3.0.0). !SUBENTRY 1
>   org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-01-23 13:23:08.027 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler_1.0.100.v20110502-1955 [32]
>   was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler
>   2 0 2012-01-23 13:23:08.027 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.updatechecker_0.0.0. !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler 2 0 2012-01-23 13:23:08.027
>   !MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui_0.0.0.
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler 2 0 2012-01-23
>   13:23:08.027 !MESSAGE Missing imported package
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.actions_0.0.0. !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler 2 0 2012-01-23 13:23:08.027
>   !MESSAGE Missing imported package
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.query_0.0.0. !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler 2 0 2012-01-23 13:23:08.027
>   !MESSAGE Missing imported package
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.updatechecker_0.0.0.
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler 2 0 2012-01-23
>   13:23:08.027 !MESSAGE Missing imported package
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations_[2.0.0,3.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler 2 0 2012-01-23 13:23:08.027
>   !MESSAGE Missing imported package
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui_[2.0.0,3.0.0). !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi
>   2 0 2012-01-23 13:23:08.027 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.updatechecker_1.1.200.v20110502-1955 [33] was
>   not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.updatechecker 2 0
>   2012-01-23 13:23:08.027 !MESSAGE Missing imported package
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.planner_[2.0.0,3.0.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me you have not included required bundles.
Stacktrace says that several packages from p2 cannot be resolved. Make sure you have resolved all dependecies that are required by p2.

Comment: p2 now it works but I can't to link my transform.cvs with the actionSetUpdate.xslt.

Comment: check also your build.properties that you export all required files.